# Equivalent Numpy array indexing returns different results

Tags: python, numpy

I'm not sure if these two indexing methods are equivalent, but intuitively they should be.

Say we have

```
x = np.arange(6).reshape(1, 3, 2)
idx = np.array([0, 1])
```

`x` is now

```
array([[[0, 1],
        [2, 3],
        [4, 5]]])
```

`x[0, :, idx]` returns (somewhat unexpectedly):

```
array([[0, 2, 4],
       [1, 3, 5]])
```

while `x[0][:, idx]` or equivalently `x.squeeze()[:, idx]` returns:

```
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5]])
```

Why does this occur? Shouldn't they return equivalent results?

Comment: Don't mix basic indexing (`:`) and advanced indexing (`idx`). [It gets messy.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#combining-advanced-and-basic-indexing)

Comment: Oh weird. Thanks!